# Creating an axis of months

Tags: matlab

I would like to create an axis from the dates  03-01-2014 to 2-28-2015 with (289*12) individual data points. So for each month the X-axis will have the month shown for every 288 data points I have in my array.

Does someone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by three function which already available in `Matlab` toolbox

first plot your data(it would be better if you say how we can regenerate your data because of that i try my own )

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
data = sin(x);
plot(x,data)
```

this 3 lines code gave me below plot for instance.
[image]

so how we could add month to axis ?! we can do it with `set` and `gca` like below

```
 set(gca,'xtick',1:6); % this xtick is very important(i said in this line i want to have x axis ticks in 1,2,3,..,6 so if your x axis is different you must change this line)
 set(gca,'xticklabel',{'03-01-2011','03-01-2012','03-01-2013','03-01-2014','03-01-2015','03-01-2016'})
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',30)
```

the output will be

[image]